# How to define the admin import format for a field using django-import-export

Tags: django, import, csv-import

I am trying to use the recently open-sourced [django-import-export](https://github.com/bmihelac/django-import-export) to import some data via the admin, and I needed to choose a custom date format.

It works, but are there problems/better ways of doing it?

**admin.py:**

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportMixin, ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources

from .models import Enrolment

class EnrolmentResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Enrolment
        fields = ('id','source','firstname','surname','date_of_birth',
                  'bonus','status','tracking_comments')

        widgets = {
                'date_of_birth': {'format': '%d/%m/%Y'},
                }

class EnrolmentAdmin(ImportExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_resource_class(self):
        if not self.resource_class:
            return EnrolmentResource
        else:
            return self.resource_class

admin.site.register(Enrolment, EnrolmentAdmin)
```

Comment: Could you provide some working example of Import with import-export in ADMIN? I do not know where should I implement some extra logic I need before insert.

Comment: @andi I think you need to use an [import-export resource](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html#base-modelresource) but if that stumps you, why not post a question here? Also, I have had some luck searching github for examples in projects so try searching github for `from import_export import resources`

Comment: @Kerridge0 good idea to get examples like that - thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following to [this](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html#admin-integration) code example, you should do something like this:

```
# ...
class EnrolmentResource(resources.ModelResource):
# ...
class EnrolmentAdmin(ImportExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = EnrolmentResource
# ...
admin.site.register(Enrolment, EnrolmentAdmin)
```